# What is the lowest Land Price I need to get ranked?

Tags: venture-towns

I have a shop that has a Land Price (LP) of 11,000. It is enough to get me a small bonus item, but still isn't high enough for me to break into the LP ratings every year.

I am tired of my people looking sad when we don't make it.

What LP do I need to start getting into these rankings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$12,000** for certain, and possibly $11,900.

It's somewhat challenging to precisely calibrate land prices, but I did some experiments. $11,800 gives "no rank", while $12,000 gives #100. So technically, $11,900 might squeak into 100th place - I wasn't able to check with the buildings available in my current save.